# What does "Unknown MySQL server host '192.12xx.xxx.xxx" mean?

Tags: python, mysql, connection

I can't connect remote server MySQL using Python.

**first.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import MySQLdb
import second

DBHostname = second.hostname
DBuser = second.user
DBPWD = second.passwd
DB = second.db

dbcon = MySQLdb.connect(host=DBHostname,user=DBuser,passwd=DBPWD,db=DB)
dbcur = dbcon.cursor()
try:
    dbcur.execute("select * from push_time where userid = %s", (e100075))
    data = dbcur.fetchall() #Fetch all of the rows from query
    for row in data : #Get Data's
        wait_time = row[2]
        print wait_time
        dbcon.commit()
except:
    dbcon.close()
```

**second.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

hostname = "192.12XX.XXX.XXX"
user = "user"
passwd = "password"
db = "dbname"
```

After running this program, I got the following error:

```
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2005, "Unknown MySQL server host '192.XXXX.XXX.XXX' (2)")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does the MySQL server allow remote connections?

Comment: try, on command line: `mysql --host=192.XXX.XXX.XXX -u <USER> <DBNAME>` and check if the RDBMS replies (you have to install mysql client on your local machine to do that)

Comment: @Marcus: yes, it allow.

Comment: @furins: I was try it. It works fine in terminal.

Comment: @Anand Do you really use 4 numbers in your second dotted-decimal. you show them in your question and second.py like this `192.**XXXX**.XXX.XXX` and `192.**12xx**.xxx.xxx`

Comment: @Vahid yes, i used four digit number.

Comment: @Anand: How the second portion of the IP address became four digits? May be you are using a wrong IP address?

Comment: @Nilani yes, i made a mistake in second decimal value.